# Перенос загрузочного и системного томов на один диск

Tags: windows, windows-10

Купил ссд и попытался перенести систему (Windows 10) на этот самый ссд, делал всё через программу MiniTool Partition Wizard 11.6 . Во время переноса выскачила ошибка, что не хватает памяти, освободите место, когда я подчистил диск, то заного запусти перенос, однако выскакивает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Because the bootable volume and system volume are not on the same disk.

И эта программа разбила хдд и ссд на всякие диски. Можно ли как-нибудь это исправить и перенести эти тома в один диск обратно?

Comment: Сохраняй важное файло на внешний винт, всё форматируй и ставь заново. Отгребёшь проблем больше, если будешь пытаться решить эту задачу.